# How to output the selected item

Tags: javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleFilterItems(item);
  });
});

function handleFilterItems(filterItem) {
  if (filterItem.getAttribute('data-control') === '' || filterItem.getAttribute('data-control') === '.all') {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]').forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('_active');
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelector('[data-control=".all"]').classList.remove('_active');
  }
  if (filterItem.classList.contains('_active')) {
    filterItem.classList.remove('_active');
    // check if no other filter item is active
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]._active').length) {
      document.querySelector('[data-control=".all"]').classList.add('_active');
    }
  } else {
    filterItem.classList.add('_active');
  }
  handleFilterTeaser();
}

function handleFilterTeaser() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(item => {
    item.classList.add('_hidden');
  });
  if (document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]._active').length === 0) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('_hidden');
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]._active').forEach(item => {
      let filterTag = item.getAttribute('data-control');
      document.querySelectorAll(filterTag).forEach(tag => {
        tag.classList.remove('_hidden');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: green;
}

button._active {
  color: tomato;
}

.list>div {
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

._hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show-choice {
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

._hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show-choice {
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 20px
}
```

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button class="_active" data-control=".all">all</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-control=".a">a</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-control=".b">b</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-control=".c">c</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="show-choice">
    <div id="choice">
      <span>a 1, b 2, a b 3, b 4, a 5, c 6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="all a">a 1</div>
  <div class="all b">b 2</div>
  <div class="all a b">a b 3</div>
  <div class="all b">b 4</div>
  <div class="all a">a 5</div>
  <div class="all c">c 6</div>
</div>
```

When the page loads, all elements are shown (the `<div id="choice">` field also shows all the options) When we select the display of certain data in the "choise" field, only the selected one should be displayed; if the selection is canceled, everything returns to its original state.

https://codepen.io/slagrach/pen/YzjQMOw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this with minimal changes is to modify the function `handleFilterTeaser()` to collect the text values of all selected elements, and then join them into a string and assign them to the element with id `choice`.

```
function handleFilterTeaser() {
  let values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(item => {
    item.classList.add('_hidden');
    });
  if (document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]._active').length === 0) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('_hidden');
        values.push(item.innerHTML);
    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]._active').forEach(item => {
      let filterTag = item.getAttribute('data-control');
      document.querySelectorAll(filterTag).forEach(tag => {
        tag.classList.remove('_hidden');
        values.push(tag.innerHTML);
      });
    });
  }
  document.querySelector('#choice').innerHTML = values.join(', ');
}
```

https://codepen.io/Urnix/pen/GRBEVGj

**Update**: The above implementation allows duplicate items in `#choice` element. I would recommend rewriting the code like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]').forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleFilterItems(index);
  });
});

function handleFilterItems(buttonIndex) {
  // Array of filters
  const filters = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]')];
  // Array of names of active filters
  let activeFilterNames = filters
    .filter(function (button) {
      return button.classList.contains('_active');
    })
    .map(function (button) {
      return button.innerHTML;
    });
  // Toggle clicked
  const clickedFilterName = filters[buttonIndex].innerHTML;
  if (activeFilterNames.includes(clickedFilterName)) {
    activeFilterNames = activeFilterNames.filter(f => f !== clickedFilterName);
  } else {
    activeFilterNames.push(clickedFilterName);
  }
  if (clickedFilterName === 'all') {
    // Turn off the rest filters if `All` clicked
    activeFilterNames = ['all'];
  } else {
    // Turn off `all` if haven any other
    const activeFilterNamesWithoutItemNamedAll = activeFilterNames.filter(f => f !== 'all');
    activeFilterNames = activeFilterNamesWithoutItemNamedAll.length ? activeFilterNamesWithoutItemNamedAll : ['all'];
  }
  // Add or remove `_active` class for each button
  filters.forEach(function (f, i) {
    if (activeFilterNames.includes(f.innerHTML)) {
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]')[i].classList.add('_active');
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-control]')[i].classList.remove('_active');
    }
  });
  handleFilterTeaser(activeFilterNames);
}

function handleFilterTeaser(filters) {
  const values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.all').forEach(tag => {
    // Add or remove `_hidden` class for each item
    if (
      [...tag.classList].find(function (clazz) {
        return filters.includes(clazz);
      })
    ) {
      tag.classList.remove('_hidden');
      // Collect visible items for display in `#choice` element
      values.push(tag.innerHTML);
    } else {
      tag.classList.add('_hidden');
    }
  });
  document.querySelector('#choice').innerHTML = values.join(', ');
}
```

https://codepen.io/Urnix/pen/OJwjPpR

Comment: and if you need to display only the title in the "choice" field [https://codepen.io/slagrach/pen/LYBjPyR](https://codepen.io/slagrach/pen/LYBjPyR)

Comment: We can grab titles like this: `values.push(tag.querySelector('.title').innerHTML)`, https://codepen.io/Urnix/pen/YzjxPQz